# How long does it take to wipe 1 GB of memory?

Tags: c, performance, memory

Today we were discussing how long Garbage Collection breaks needs. And were wondering how long it would take to simply wipe 1 Gigabyte of memory. What would it take?

Comment: How long does it take to eat a pizza? It depends on who is eating it, and what size and kind of pizza it is. Same issues apply to your question.

Comment: Oh, but you know, just the order of magnitude would be interesting. Is it more like days or nanoseconds? Just to get a feel.

Comment: It would take a few seconds worth of effort to call memset and fire up a profiler.

Comment: It should be noted that garbage collecting doesn't require you to actually erase the memory a garbage-collected object occupied.

Comment: With a powerful and close EMP, a nanosecond or so. Using trained ants, years.

Comment: It will also depend on external situations which can greatly vary.  If the OS needs to do any swapping to make your memory pages available, that will greatly slow down the operation.

Comment: Anon: I know, but a garbage collector will be at least linear on the allocated memory. I was just trying to know what the principal problem of garbage collection is. 

Imagine you could read and write a Gigabyte of memory in 1 ms. Then you could mark and compact your whole Gigabyte in what? 20 ms? Then sun wouldn't bother making a G1 highly complex Garbage Collector. So it is the slowness of reading and writing memory that makes good Garbage Collection algorithms necessary.

Comment: it is absolutely not the slowness of reading and writing memory that place a need on garbage collection. it is fragmentation and programming ease that GC (and other allocators -- i.e., doug lea's malloc) is aimed to solve, and the slowness comes from  the complexity of these algorithms.

Comment: But look, Hassan, Speaking in terms of complexity, one mark-and-compact run over the whole allocated area, in complexity terms, it runs in O(n log n), doesn't it? Mark and copy probably runs in O(n), doesn't it? All I want is a feeling for O(n) is when it comes to 1 GB and memory. I'm sorry to appear naiv.

Comment: Hassan: What I want to say is: sun is working hard to have Garbage Collection breaks be shorter than 20 ms. And that is what I have no feeling for: How long would they be if we just did a trivial mark-and-compact? How much is 20 ms when it comes to memory? :)

Comment: Hello Jack I have edited my answer with a more accurate strategy you should be taking to get a felling of the cost of garbage collection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On my machine, about one second:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


const long long int NUM =  1024*1024*1024/8;

int main(void) {
    long long int* ptr = malloc(NUM  * sizeof ptr);
    printf("Gigabytes: %lld\n",NUM * sizeof ptr / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
    for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++) {
        ptr[i]=1l;
    }
}
```

I then run the following (which unwillingly measures the allocation time, too:

```
$ gcc -O3 -std=c99 mem.c -o mem
$ time ./mem
Gigabytes: 1

real    0m1.056s
user    0m0.205s
sys  0m0.845s
```

Comment: Plus 15 seconds to type the program to do it, apparently. +1

Comment: Unless there is some specific reason you need the 7 bytes of 0x00 and 1 byte of 0x01 pattern, I would highly recommend using memset().

Comment: Memset is almost certainly going to be faster than a naive loop.

Comment: This answer is unrealistic and naive... and what on earth does it have to do with garbage collection ?

Comment: My colleges feel that you should set it to 0 for it to be "wiped."

Comment: You should do that to sensitive data, foh shizzle. However, doing to for everything is wastefull.

Comment: Hashan Syed is correct. This answer has nothing to do with garbage collection and, as others have mentioned, if erasing the memory were indeed required, memset would perform a heck of a lot better.

Comment: 14 up votes is astounding, people see a bit of code and get overly excited :/

Comment: This is including the time to malloc the buffer (which may be on the order of the time to wipe the buffer) and uses a very naive reimplementation of `memset`.  The actual time should be rather less than a second.

Comment: @nes1983 Sorry but I don't believe your result. With `-O3` `gcc` shall have eventually removed the full content of your loop to optimize, unless you declare the pointer with `volatile` explicitly. Could you please show me the assembly of this piece of code by passing `-S` to `gcc`? Also what's your `gcc` version and platform info? Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

You need to consider many elements here. I doubt a general-purpose garbage collector cleans up memory when it unlinks it -- that would be a waste of time. That plus Garbage collection tends not to be O(N). Garbage collection usually has a few routines that it will run --  the simplest one to mention here would be compaction, compaction itself is based on the statistics of the distribution of allocated memory. The other phases will have similar complexities..

**-- edit after comments below and in the question --**

Your chosen answer does not bring you closer to that feeling -- in fact it is entirely misleading -- as it is not iterating over an in-memory data structure. It is just crudely wiping memory, which is not the job of a garbage collector.

**A more accurate answer**

If you wanted to get a real feel for the garbage collector I suggest writing a .NET or Java app and initializing a gig + of memory in differing sizes of objects and then randomly droping   100-300mb of objects, and then recreating them again of random sizes; Do this for a few passes to mix things up. Follow this by disabling the collector, dropping a gig worth of objects and then forcing a manual collections; This last manual collection is what you want to benchmark -- and you want to do this a 100 times or so and plot the result.

**A note On 20 ms**

I'm sure there are ways to get a collector to behave in a real-time pattern if that is what you desire. A collector does not have to do a full sweep, it can be written to perform as a collection of atomic operations and you could disable the collection phase on a realtime-timeout -- i.e., 20 ms. In this case it would have done a partial collection which would still be usefull.

You would have to adjust the strategy I mentioned to measure how much can be done in 20ms. Be sure to understand that how much is collected is more dependant on the amount of objects present rather than the size of them. So I suggest capturing both values should you decide to formally test the GC.

Answer (score 2):

One would expect that to return 1 GIG of memory back to free pool would be just some simple pointer manipulation. GCs don't generally clear the memory returned back.

The time to allocate a 1 GIG memory depends on what is going on in the O/S at the time - you have to set up page tables etc...

Answer (score 2):

I measured memory bandwidth on several recent desktop models some time ago, testing with bursty transfers, and came up with a consistent number: roughly 5 gigabytes per second.  Which matches very well with Niko's number, 0.205 seconds for a gig.  The 0.845 seconds of system time is burned on making the memory available.  Which has much more to do with the speed of your hard drive, the state of your paging file and how many pages of other programs are loaded in RAM than memory bandwidth.

In other words, anything you measure is likely to be off by 400% or more.  Sometimes much more.

Comment: (+1) good advice :D. @jack disable the hd swap area (page file in windows) before you run any tests, and have enough ram in the machine.